# how to solve encoding error on django when taking input from forms

Tags: python, django

i get an error when i try to get data from a post request i'm trying to make a user model (apart from the built in one could be any model with 3 inputs )

```
File "C:\Users\o00489658\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticf
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\o00489658\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\w
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\o00489658\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\b
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "C:\Users\o00489658\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\e
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\o00489658\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\e
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\o00489658\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\e
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\o00489658\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py"
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\Users\o00489658\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py"
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 9737: illegal multibyte sequence
```

### my models.py

```
from django.db import models
class kullanici(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(unique=True,primary_key=True)
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    LastName=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id+' '+(self.Name)+' '+(self.LastName)
```

---

### view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from myapp import forms
from myapp.forms import UsernameForm

def homepage(request):
    mydict ={'inserted':'inserted via django '}
    return render(request,"Linked_page.html",context=mydict)
def secondpage(request):
    form = forms.UsernameForm()
    form2 =UsernameForm(data=request.POST)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=forms.UsernameForm(request.POST)
        print('valid as in entry standard')
        print(form)
        form2.save()

    return render(request,'onyuz.html',{'form':form})

def Users(request):
    userlist=kullanici.objects.order_by('id')
    mydict ={'access_records':userlist}
    return render(request,"onyuzmodetrator.html",context=mydict)
```

---

### form

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import kullanici

class UsernameForm(forms.Form):
    Name=forms.CharField()
    LastName=forms.CharField()
    id=forms.IntegerField()
    class Meta():
        model=kullanici
    fields='__all__'
```

---

### html İt has {% load static %} on the top

```
  <form class=""  method="POST">
    {{form}}
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="submit" name="" placeholder="Submit">

  </form>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form class=""  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

you can add **

> enctype="multipart/form-data"

** in forms

Comment: You are writing forms and again calling models,don't do that keep any one like

Answer (score 0):

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import kullanici

class UsernameForm(forms.modelForm):
 class Meta():
    model=kullanici
    fields='__all__'
```

and remove id in models no need, default django take care of id

Answer (score 0):

i solved it its like a syntax error if you use Models instead of models something like this